# Reading a file with a specified delimiter for newline

Tags: python, file-io, python-2.7, io

I have a file in which lines are separated using a delimeter say `.`. I want to read this file line by line, where lines should be based on presence of `.` instead of newline.

One way is:

```
f = open('file','r')
for line in f.read().strip().split('.'):
   #....do some work
f.close()
```

But this is not memory efficient if my file is too large. Instead of reading a whole file together I want to read it line by line.

`open` supports a parameter 'newline' but this parameter only takes `None, '', '\n', '\r', and '\r\n'` as input as mentioned [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html).

**Is there any way to read files line efficiently but based on a pre-specified delimiter?**

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could use a generator:

```
def myreadlines(f, newline):
  buf = ""
  while True:
    while newline in buf:
      pos = buf.index(newline)
      yield buf[:pos]
      buf = buf[pos + len(newline):]
    chunk = f.read(4096)
    if not chunk:
      yield buf
      break
    buf += chunk

with open('file') as f:
  for line in myreadlines(f, "."):
    print line
```

Comment: Could be simplified a bit by changing the start of the outer loop to `for chunk in iter(functools.partial(f.read, 4096), ''): buf += chunk` and adding `if buf: yield buf` after the loop (not inside).

Comment: @Harvey Nice! Is there a reason to use `functools.partial(f.read, 4096)` instead of `lambda: f.read(4096)`?

Comment: Lambdas are discouraged, and all the cool kids use `partial`. There's probably a good reason. For example, lambdas can't be pickled and therefore can't be passed to thread pools.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a more efficient answer, using `FileIO` and `bytearray` that I used for parsing a PDF file -

```
import io
import re


# the end-of-line chars, separated by a `|` (logical OR)
EOL_REGEX = b'\r\n|\r|\n'  

# the end-of-file char
EOF = b'%%EOF'



def readlines(fio):
    buf = bytearray(4096)
    while True:
        fio.readinto(buf)
        try:
            yield buf[: buf.index(EOF)]
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            break
        for line in re.split(EOL_REGEX, buf):
            yield line


with io.FileIO("test.pdf") as fio:
    for line in readlines(fio):
        ...
```

The above example also handles a custom EOF. If you don't want that, use this:

```
import io
import os
import re


# the end-of-line chars, separated by a `|` (logical OR)
EOL_REGEX = b'\r\n|\r|\n'  


def readlines(fio, size):
    buf = bytearray(4096)
    while True:
        if fio.tell() >= size:
            break               
        fio.readinto(buf)            
        for line in re.split(EOL_REGEX, buf):
            yield line

size = os.path.getsize("test.pdf")
with io.FileIO("test.pdf") as fio:
    for line in readlines(fio, size):
         ...
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to preprocess the file to generate newlines where you want.

Here's an example using perl (assuming you want the string 'abc' to be the newline):

```
perl -pe 's/abc/\n/g' text.txt > processed_text.txt
```

If you also want to ignore the original newlines, use the following instead:

```
perl -ne 's/\n//; s/abc/\n/g; print' text.txt > processed_text.txt
```