# Python: How can I read till ETX (End of Text) Hex 03 in a file?

Tags: python-2.7

I have a file with multiple lines and right now I read 20480 bytes at once:

```
while True:
    data = fh.read(20480)
    if data == '':
        fh.close()
        break
```

I have another file where ETX is used as the delimiter. How do I read characters till ETX is reached?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to read multiple records, each delimited by ASCII 3, then the `myreadlines` function in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16260061/reading-a-file-with-a-specified-delimiter-for-newline) will do the trick.

The only difference is using the character with value 3 as the delimiter, instead of period, like this:

```
delim = chr(3)
with open('file') as f:
 for line in myreadlines(f, delim):
  print line
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please let me know why 4096 bytes are being read in this function:
`def myreadlines(f, newline):
  buf = ""
  while True:
    while newline in buf:
      pos = buf.index(newline)
      yield buf[:pos]
      buf = buf[pos + len(newline):]
    chunk = f.read(4096)
    if not chunk:
      yield buf
      break
    buf += chunk`

Comment: I think there is nothing special about the value 4096 (it is just a common block size)  and another value would work equally well.